# Magento customer login doesn't work after adding SSL

Tags: login, ssl, magento-1.9.2.1

I'm using magento version: 1.9.2.1. And faced a problem with customer login with ssl certificate. I tried adding session domain and path. Doesn't help. When i try to login it just says welcome, and after refresh it says that i'm not logged in.

Anyone know how to fix this issue?

It only happens with SSL certificate enabled. If i remove it. It starts to work.